# I how can I return objects in Django?

Tags: python, django

The following

> Model.objects.all()[:10]

Will return 10 records ordered by primary key.  I'm trying to get the objects in reverse order.  In other words if my highest primary key was 5000, I'm trying to get 5000, 4999, 4998...

I have tried:

```
Model.objects.reverse().all()[:10]
```

But it does not appear to affect the order

Comment: "Will return 10 records ordered by primary key." Will it? Did you tell the model to order that way by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
Model.objects.order_by('-id')[:10]
```